# Plaid only giving "ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED" for Capital One

Tags: ruby, reactjs, finance, plaid

I'm using plaid to attempt to get transactions from a linked account. In sandbox I was not getting any errors but once I moved into development I started `seeing "ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED"` while trying to get transactions. I'm using the plaid react component and plaid ruby gem. I suspect that there isn't an error in my code as much as the flow through Plaids api which like the following

User interacts with Link -> logs into account with creds -> account is linked and public_token is returned -> public_token exchanged for access_token which is stored in DB -> access_token used to lookup transactions -> Plaid returns error. -> take user through update mode -> lookup transactions -> error -> rinse and repeat.

Below is where I'm looking up transaction and where I get the error.

```
    start_date = Date.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, 1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date = Date.new(date[0].to_i, date[1].to_i, -1).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    plaid_env = Rails.application.config.plaid_env
    client_id = Rails.application.config.client_id
    secret = Rails.application.config.secret
    public_key = Rails.application.config.public_key

    client = Plaid::Client.new(env: plaid_env,
                               client_id: client_id,
                               secret: secret,
                               public_key: public_key)

    transaction_response = client.transactions.get(access_token, start_date, end_date)

    transactions = transaction_response.transactions
```

Comment: can you post the backtrace errors?

Comment: There isn't a stack, its an api response. I got a response from Plaid, it's actually on their end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Plaid support this one is actually on their end.

> Plaid Support Nov 8, 2019,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to Plaid Support!
>
> I've confirmed that there is an issue with our Capital integration
>   that is causing this issue. Our engineering team is aware of this
>   issue and currently working to resolve it. We will reach out here as
>   soon as this is resolved.
>
> Please let us know if you have any further questions or concerns.
>   Thanks for your patience while we work to resolve this!
>
> Best, Phillippa Plaid Suppor

I asked if there was an ETA or Workaround and here is their reply.

> We are dedicating ongoing resources to resolving this issue, but
>   unfortunately Capital One hasn't been cooperative and we can’t
>   anticipate a timeline for a technical resolution at this point. There
>   isn't currently a workaround that I'm aware of. I sincerely apologize
>   for the inconvenience that this causes – this issue is unique to our
>   Capital One integration, and does not affect the other institutions
>   that we support.
>
> We'll be sure to reach back out here as soon as we have any updates!
>
> Best, Nicole

Plaid Support

Comment: Ya. It's really annoying. I've given up on Plaid.